# Delete only files from HDFS not subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to delete files from an HDFS directory, but not delete subdirectories?
I have a path like: `/hdfs/test/folder/` without knowing what is inside.

I want all files to be deleted, for example:

`/hdfs/test/folder/file.txt`

but all subdirectories are ignored:

```
/hdfs/test/folder/data/
/hdfs/test/folder/pipline/
```

i know only command `hdfs dfs -rm -r /hdfs/test/folder/*` but it's deleted all inside directory.

Comment: You could use the Java Hadoop client to walk the file tree and check for only file type paths

Answer (score 0):

hdfs dfs -rm -r /hdfs/test/folder/file*.txt

If the file name in the specified directory meets the conditions, it will be deleted.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I want to delete all files without knowing their names and their extensions. Even if they don't have extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I took advice of @OneCricketeer.
I used the Spark Scala API and was able to filter and delete all files:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val d = new Path(s"/hdfs/test/folder/")
fs.listStatus(d).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).foreach(n => fs.delete(n))
```